# Silverlight with C++.Net

Tags: .net, c++, silverlight

Can you use C++.Net for writting a Silverlight application? Not use C# or VB.Net as the backend language but C++.Net

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check [this](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/5329/164934.aspx#164934). A google search would have answered your query.

Update: I was wrong. Apologies for that. Mark has answered it correctly. 
Mark : You can use any language so long as it compiles to pure managed code. For example there are Silverlight applications using IronPython, IronRuby. The only restriction is you can't have any native code, or use parts of the FCL that are restricted by Silverlight (e.g. P/Invoke)

Comment: how does that link answer the question? It is about hosting a Silverlight control, while the original questioner asked about using C++ as the backend language

Answer (score 3):

You can use any language so long as it compiles to pure managed code. For example there are Silverlight applications using IronPython, IronRuby. The only restriction is you can't have any native code, or use parts of the FCL that are restricted by Silverlight (e.g. P/Invoke)