# Calling C++ Code from Silverlight Web Application

Tags: c++, silverlight, networking

Is it possible to call C++ functions/Use C++ classes from a silverlight web app?

I'm making a little game with a client-server architecture, the client would be in C#/Silverlight and be hosted on a web page, and the server would be made with C++.  Both parts have some common things between them (Most notably the structures for the 'data' that will be transferred back and forth), and I'd like to make it for I don't have duplicate code in 2 languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although C++ is not an officially supported language for Silverlight, in theory if you can compile C++ to CLR managed code, you can run it in Silverlight.  But Microsoft seems to have backed away from C++ for CLR.

Relevant links:

- http://forums.silverlight.net/t/8366.aspx/1
- [Silverlight with C++.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680715/silverlight-with-c-net)